# Hide the OK button in windows mobile 6.5

Tags: compact-framework, c#-2.0, menubar, windows-mobile-6.5

I have a winmo application running on win mobile 6.5 using the 2.0 ce framework:

On some forms, I make use of the menu bar to have custom menu items, as seen below
[image: Menu bar with custom menu items "More" and "Cancel"]

The "More" and "Cancel" buttons have events wired up so that I can actually make the form behave how I want to.  But the problem is the "OK" that is always there by default and just closes the current form.  I want to remove this completely so that it looks like this

[image: I don't want OK to be displayed at all]:

But from what I have been researching so far, it is impossible.  I have come across solutions to remove the whole menu bar (I still need the other buttons) or to disable the OK button (but even having it there will confuse the users)

Is this possible?

- would be cool to also remove the windows "start" button, but not necessary

Answer (score 3):

You can "dynamically" show/hide the Star icon when using small code BEFORE the window/form is created: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/05/10/windows-mobile-kiosk-mode-series-part-1/

The trick is to just change one registry key BEFORE create windows/form:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Shell\BubbleTiles]
"HardwareStartKeyEnabled"=dword:00000001

set to 1 to hide the start icon for new windows and set to 0 to have new windows show a start icon.

The change will NOT affect already open/created windows/forms. Only newly ones will be affected.

Answer (score 1):

**To Hide/disappear the Ok button or x (close) button,**

Enable, controlbox=false.

**To disappear/Hide the whole header or menu bar,**

Use, WindowState=Maximized.